# Creating HTML Lists Purely in CSS

Tags: html, css

Trying to make it easy for a disabled friend to enter content into the site that I created for him without excessive typing, is there some way in CSS to create bulleted and ordered lists using existing line breaks or tabs rather than putting in list elements? These examples are for unordered but ordered is also needed.

For example, this:

```
<div class="Unordered"><br />
    List item 1<br />
    List item 2<br />
    List item 3<br />
</div>
```

. . . with the br coming from nl2br() and CSS something like this?

```
.Unordered {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.Unordered br {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

I'm trying to produce a list with the visual appearance created by a regular list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am not adverse to doing this using PHP either.

Comment: Have you consider writing a small markup language that compiles to HTML instead?

Comment: Yes, doing it in PHP is also an option and I even experimented last night with the possibility but didn’t get it working.

Answer (score 1):

use "before" for span tag to make bullet!

```css
.Unordered {
    margin: auto;
    float:left;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.Unordered br {
    list-style-type: disc;
}

span:before {
  content: ' \25CF';
  font-size: 20px;
}

span{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="Unordered">
<span>List item 1</span>
<span>List item 2</span>
<span>List item 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but going through all that extra typing defeats the purpose and is not what I’m looking for, which I suspect is not possible. If each line needs to be surrounded by span tags, it might as well use li tags instead, with simple ul to make it into a list.

Comment: you don't want to use any tag surround the texts?why?

Comment: As my questions says, I am trying to relieve a disabled friend of unnecessary typing.

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate this using background coloration where you have control over the height of each line by setting `line-height`

```css
.Unordered {
   padding-left:20px;
   margin:10px;
   line-height:1.2em;
   background:
    radial-gradient(circle 0.3em,#000 86%,transparent 100%) 0 0/20px 1.2em repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div class="Unordered">
    List item 1<br>
    List item 2<br>
    List item 3<br>
</div>

<div class="Unordered">
    List item 1<br>
    List item 2<br>
    List item 3<br>
    List item 4<br>
    List item 5<br>
</div>
```

Or like below if you are able to consider a different tag for the line break than `<br>`

```css
.Unordered,
.Ordered{
   padding-left:20px;
   margin:10px;
   counter-reset:num;
}
/*Line break*/
.Unordered z::before,
.Ordered z::before{
   content:"\A";
   white-space:pre;
}
/*bullet*/
.Unordered z::after {
   content:"•";
}
/*numver*/
.Ordered z::after {
   content:counter(num) ".";
   counter-increment:num;
}
.Unordered z:last-of-type,
.Ordered z:last-of-type{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Unordered"><z></z>
    List item 1<z></z>
    List item 2<z></z>
    List item 3<z></z>
</div>

<div class="Ordered"><z></z>
    List item 1<z></z>
    List item 2<z></z>
    List item 3<z></z>
    List item 4<z></z>
    List item 5<z></z>
</div>
```

Another hacky idea (I insist on **hacky**)

```css
.Unordered,
.Ordered{
   padding-left:20px;
   margin:10px;
   line-height:1.2em;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.Unordered:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:1.2em;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
   background:
    radial-gradient(circle 0.3em,#000 86%,transparent 100%) 0 0/20px 1.2em repeat-y;
}
.Ordered:before{
  content:"1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20";  /*yes manually write them all !!*/
  position:absolute;
  top:1.2em;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Unordered"><br>
    List item 1<br>
    List item 2<br>
    List item 3<br>
</div>

<div class="Ordered"><br>
    List item 1<br>
    List item 2<br>
    List item 3<br>
    List item 4<br>
    List item 5<br>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be a way to do it and will give it a try once I’m back at my desk although I used unordered lists only as an example. I will also need to do ordered lists.

Comment: Interesting idea but no, if all the extra tags are needed, it defeats the purpose and some of the lists are quite long. The <br /> is created automatically by the PHP nl2br() function.

Comment: @DonP like you used nl2br() to convert new line to br, you do the same logic to convert new line to another tag. I didn't add extra tags but considered the idea that you can convert new line to something that you can better control than br

Comment: @Temani Afif nl2br() is being applied site-wide, not just on lists and these lists are surrounded by other content that might be adversely affected by introducing additional elements. What did you have in mind and how would it be done? Anyway, your first idea seems to work well for unordered lists other than giving an extra bullet at the top due to the return after the opening div tag. As a temporary workaround until a solution is found, that return can simply be left out.

Comment: @DonP you can easily fix the extra bullet with any technique, ex: https://jsfiddle.net/p1nLaq05/ ... by the way, you will need an effort somewhere (either backend or frontend). I think you would agree that if you cannot change the markup, or add an extra backend function or anything then it's propably impossible to achieve what you want. Order list require different numbers so having only br cannot achieve this. There is no magic CSS technique unless you are ready to write hacky one (check the update)

Comment: @Temani Afif I don't at all mind a hacky one that works and it does so wonderfully!  As long as I make a list that is long enough to handle most eventualities, I can see no problem with it. (One list from the site that I'm using as a test has 35.)  It's certainly not something I ever would have thought of doing! I don't know if it can handle nested lists or whether it's even necessary (not sure the site has any so no problem if it doesn't) but just for fun I gave it a try with interesting results. Anyway, thank you!